# Adding a function in LLVM (haskell bindings) when the number of parameters is not known at compile time

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, language-design, llvm

**Background**: I have written a toy Lisp interpreter that I am trying to add LLVM JIT functionality to.  For the moment, have imposed the following limitations:

- Only integer values are allowed in functions
- Variables may only reference formal parameters

**Given**:

```
compile :: [Value] -- List of Formal Parameters
        -> [Value] -- Body of function
        -> CodeGenModule(Function a)`
```

**Question**: How do I generate a function where the number of parameters equals the length of the Formal Parameters list?

Comment: A good start might be to either help me understand `forall f g r . FunctionArgs f g (CodeGenFunction r ())`

Comment: would you like to share you experience of using haskell binding of LLVM? which version do you used? :)

Comment: @Wu: LLVM 2.9 with the llvm binding from [commit 729514](https://github.com/bos/llvm/commit/72951414d7b7b377ee1a040fae2b043b7747ceff).  [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406067/haskell-llvm-binding-linker-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible to do this with just the EDSL from `LLVM.Core` (the types are indeed quite hairy), but if you look at [`LLVM.FFI.Core`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/llvm/0.9.1.2/doc/html/LLVM-FFI-Core.html), you'll find the lower-level functionality for [manipulating LLVM function types](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/llvm/0.9.1.2/doc/html/LLVM-FFI-Core.html#g:6) and [creating LLVM functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/llvm/0.9.1.2/doc/html/LLVM-FFI-Core.html#g:15). This leads to the following plan of action:

- Create a `TypeRef` for your function with `functionType`.
- Add this function to your module using `addFunction`.
- Populate it with basic blocks by using `appendBasicBlock`/`insertBasicBlock`. Use `getParam` to reference function arguments inside your basic blocks.

It should be possible to utilise the nice monadic EDSL syntax for constructing the basic blocks. Also, look at [`LLVM.Core.Util`](https://github.com/bos/llvm/blob/master/LLVM/Core/Util.hs), it contains some helper functions for working with the FFI layer.